# How to forward a heroku domain to a custom domain-- getting error "Domain is invalid"

Tags: heroku, dns, nameservers

I have looked on here for answers but haven't found any that address this issue.

I have tried typing the following and all gave me the error `! Domain is invalid`

`heroku domains:add http://www.mydomainhere.com`

`heroku domains:add www.mydomainhere.com`

`heroku domains:add mydomainhere.com`

I didn't use any special characters, just lowercase letters. I purchased the domain name through A Small Orange.

Comment: The bottom two should definitely work.

Comment: But if they didn't is there anything else I can check?

Comment: create a support ticket :)

Comment: FWIW I had the same error, which was resolved by removing the http:// prefix